# Finding all posts shared from my facebook post using PHP Facebook SKD

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm Facebook PHP SDK, and I am trying to find out how to find out who shared one of my posts so that I can comment on it (on the sharing).

The post result on the graph explorer does not show me who shared the post just and I just have just the number of shares:

> ..."shares": { "count": 7 },...

I also tried the graph explorer /postid/shares and /postid/shared but neither worked.

Any example using the PHP SDK would be highly appreciated.

thanks 
Eco

Answer (score 0):

Use https://graph.facebook.com/OBJECT_ID/sharedposts
with OBJECT_ID is the status ID, the post ID you want to look up.

Try this: [https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=745383555478363%2Fsharedposts](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=745383555478363/sharedposts)

Or read the detailed answer from here: [Information of re-shared status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17373204/information-of-re-shared-status)